# why argv works, but lineptr don't ? (pointer and array in C)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *lineptr[] = {"abc","defg","hijk"};
    char **lp = lineptr;
    int nlines = 3;
    while(nlines-- > 0){
        printf("%s\n", *lineptr++);
    }

    while(--argc)
        printf("%s%s",*++argv,(argc>1) ? " " : "");
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lineptr` is an **array** (of pointers), `argv` is a **pointer** (to pointers). Arrays and pointers are different. See section 6 of the [comp.lang.c. faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: I think argv is also a array of pointers, bucause the declarations of them are the same. So why they have the same declarations but lineptr is an array and argv is a pointer?

Comment: When used in a parameter, the array syntax is eye-candy for pointer. ie `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is 100% absolutely identical to `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (also `int foo(int bar[])` is 100% identical to `int foo(int *bar)`).

Comment:  thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You had a bug at the first *printf* statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *lineptr[] = {"abc","defg","hijk"};
    char **lp = lineptr;
    int nlines = 3;
    while(nlines-- > 0){
        printf("%s\n", lineptr[nlines]); /* see the difference to your line */
    }

    while(--argc)
        printf("%s%s",*++argv,(argc>1) ? " " : "");
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, it's better to use a FOR-loop when handling arrays, because it's easier to manage and less prone to errors.

```
for(int i=0; i<nlines; i++) /* nlines = 3 */
{
    printf("%s\n", lineptr[i]);
}
```

Comment: your coding is right, but it is not my intention. I want to learn the difference between Pointer and array in C. So both as a array with pointer, why *++argv works, but *lineptr++  not?